# Giant elseif chain, giant switch, or tiny switch with functions?

Tags: php, navigation, structure

I have a 9000-line PHP file which consists of about 30 discrete areas, navigated to through `$_POST` variables. So one might be ...

```
elseif (isset($_POST['view_user']) 
     || isset($_POST['edit_user']) 
     || isset($_POST['process_user_status']))
```

... and so on. I probably have around 75 points of entry to these thirty areas, all handled by long elseif isset chains like the above.

I've been thinking about changing this to something a little more sane. The ideas I've come up with so far:

1) Boil the posts down to a boolean, and use that in the elseif chain. So the above would be boiled down to `elseif ($area_user)`, with `$area_user` being set to `true` if any of the `$_POST`s above were set. But this isn't really addressing the complexity issue.

2) Use cases instead of elseif. So the above would become...

```
case (isset($_POST['view_user'])):
case (isset($_POST['edit_user'])):
case (isset($_POST['process_user_status'])):
    do stuff;
    break;
```

But, again, while it removes the elseif syntax, it's just replacing it with something that, while slightly more manageable, might still be hiding the true problem.

3) Use functions. So at the top of the page, I have a similar switch statement, but instead of it being in the middle of the page going directly into the script area, it calls a function, so instead of 'do stuff' it might call `UserArea($_POST['whatever'])`. This has the advantage of moving all `$_POST` variables outside of the meat of the script and concentrating them into the navigation and function calls. However, it will require lots of global function declarations that currently I don't need to do because the branches of the elseif are in the global scope.

4) Refactor entirely with a full MVC split, templates, etc. Would love to but not an option at this moment. Just be happy I have the model split off, but the view and controller have to coexist for now.

As I've been writing this I'm convincing myself more and more of 3, but I wanted to see what you kind folks thought. What should be the best practice navigation for a situation like this?

Comment: case 2) won't work - case only works on constants.

Comment: You'd think but I tested it and it seems to work: `$a = 'foo'; switch (true) { case isset($b): echo 'no'; break; case isset($a): echo 'yes'; break; }` echoes 'yes' on PHP 5.2.8.

Comment: @Femaref: PHP does not have that limitation. That only applies to statically-typed languages.

Comment: why php, why would you allow that...

Comment: @Femaref ["The case expression may be *any expression that evaluates to a simple type*, that is, integer or floating-point numbers and strings..."](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: How much redundancy is there in the "do stuff"s? If there's significant redundancy then you should factor the redundant code off into functions, but if not, the giant switch statement might not be too bad.

Comment: Don't tell *us* to "just be happy I have the model split off", we're not the ones who have to maintain a 9000 line PHP file :p

Comment: @Brandon Bohrer, No redundancy; moving them into functions would be purely organizational. (And, possibly, moving data from `$_POST` variables into the function call and out of the functions themselves)

Comment: @meagar, Heh. Well without the model split off it'd be 14,000 lines ;) I was just heading off at the pass people urging me to do that.

Comment: @Andrew If there's no redundancy then I don't have much of an opinion either way. IMO the most important thing is that it's easy to navigate, so if you have standard names that you use to refer to the different sets of cases, you might want to split it up into functions with those names, or possibly put them as comments at the start of each block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more option for you: A dictionary of handler functions.

Put all your *potential* $_POST keys ('view_user' etc.) in an associative array pointing to the function (name) that handles them. Then, in place of your ifelse chain, iterate through the *actual* $_POST keys until you find a match in the array and call the associated function.

Now you can move your handler functions into other files without pain, though you may need to add some parameters to that dynamic function call. This kind of dispatch is used by most MVC frameworks (against patterns in the path, rather than form or querystring data).

```
// Untested, but something like this
$handlers = array(
  'view_user' => 'UserArea',
  'edit_user' => 'UserArea',
  'view_document' => 'DocManagement', // for example
  // etc...
);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(array_key_exists($key, $handlers)){
    call_user_func($handlers[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not use this solution. However, for opening my eyes to it, you get the checkmark. The solution I went with was to use a switch  to shrink all of the entry points into their actual destinations, then use a giant elseif chain to check if the variable matched what the switch had set it to. Not ideal, but it works for now. :)